# I want to remove Underline in Bootstrap Link

Tags: css, reactjs, hyperlink, react-bootstrap

I have seen similar questions but solution suggests to change it through css.
I tried but unable to reproduce the solution for my code. Currently link is looking like this
I also explored `react-bootstrap` docs but hey haven't mentioned any specific tag to remove that styling

[image]

I want to remove that Blue Under Line.

Code :

```
                      <ListGroup.Item>
                        <Link to={`/panelmember/${item._id}`}>
                          <Card.Title as="h2">
                            <strong>{item.name}</strong>
                          </Card.Title>
                        </Link>
                      </ListGroup.Item>
```

Is there Any way to add Short code inside the `<Link>` tag ? Or if we have to customize it in `index.css` then can you suggest any solution.

Comment: Give a classname from `Link`, and give `text-decoration:none` to the class in your styles

Comment: Tried but not working , `Link {
  text-decoration: none;
}` in `index.css`

Comment: You cannot give Link directly. You need to give a classname for the link and try with it

Comment: Bootstrap adds `!important` to lots of it's utilities unless you load it via SASS and set the variable `$enable-important-utilities: false;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.links {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<Link className={`links`} to={`/panelmember/${item._id}`}>
  <Card.Title as="h2">
    <strong>{item.name}</strong>
  </Card.Title>
</Link>
```

Like this

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap 4 makes use of Sass for its styling (Sass is a pre-processor scripting language that is interpreted or compiled into Cascading Style Sheets - see https://sass-lang.com/). See https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/theming/ for details on Bootstrap theming.

If you are using Sass to compile your CSS file, you can override the default Bootstrap styling for links (which is *underline*) by adding the following to the scss file (before importing bootstrap):

$link-decoration: none;

Comment: IMO this is the correct answer. To manipulate the bootstrap library effectively, you should load it via SASS and override the default behavior.

Updated Docs for 5.3: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/customize/sass/